# How to convert curl command to $.ajax() call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I'm trying to make a Zomato API call with jquery ajax, but they are providing a curl command.

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "user-key: key" "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/cities"
```

How to convert this to $.ajax() call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/cities',
  headers: {
    'user-key': 'put your key in here'
  }
  success: function(response, status, xhr) {
    // Handle the response here.
  }
});
```

Refer to the [JQuery API docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info.